# Как undefined преобразуется в строку?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [undefined, undefined];
console.log(a.join()); // тут undefined преобразуются в пустую строку
console.log(String(undefined)); // а тут в строку 'undefined'
console.log('' + undefined); // и тут в 'undefined'
```

Где логика?

Comment: У меня была ситуация, когда `a.b.c.d` (и все `undefined`) в Firefox работало без ошибок, а в Chromium ошибка была. Повторить сейчас не смог, но такая ситуация точно была.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не сразу поймете **логику**, пока не почитаете стандарт, как и во многих языках с автоматическим приведением типа. Выстраивать возможные связи не зная определенных тонкостей при управлении типами - бесполезно в любом языке со слабой типизацией, ведь разработчики делают так, как было удобно им, а другие разработчики как удобно им. Возможно ваши интересы сойдутся с ними и тогда вы будете в языке **"как рыба в воде"**, но могут и не сойтись..

Проведем маленький тест..**Чему равны следующие операции?**

```
console.log(NaN === NaN);
console.log([] + []);
```

Подобным операциям есть логическое объяснение, но у многих людей эти операции связанные с типами на javascript за всю историю вызывали дикие споры, ведь это гибкий язык. А гибкость его необычайна, и это имеет две стороны.

Вы можете быстро написать какой-то функционал, а можете с кривыми руками написать **такое от чего будет дергаться глаз**. В целом так с любым языком, знайте как его применять и у вас не будет проблем. Конечно же, динамическая типизация нравится не всем и в последнее время появился типизированный язык TypeScript, который имеет свой синтаксис с автоматиматическим конвертированием в Javascript. *Все думают по разному, может вы сторонник строгой типизации и он подойдет вам больше?*

[Есть интересное видео](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) с конференции, где люди обсуждали подобные операции.

Вернемся к вопросу и откроем [сайт **Mozila** с описанием стандарта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript):

```
var a = [undefined, undefined]; 
console.log(a.join());
```

> **Array.prototype.join()** -Преобразует все элементы массива в строки и объединяет их в одну большую строку. Элемент массива с типом
>   undefined или null преобразуется в пустую строку. [Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
console.log(String(undefined));
console.log('' + undefined);
```

Первый случай описан в [официальном стандарте](http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.8) ([англ](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)) в пункте 9.8.

Второй случай описан на официальном сайте Mozila:

> undefined является свойством глобального объекта, то есть, это
>   переменная в глобальной области видимости. Начальным значением
>   undefined является примитивное значение undefined.
>   Переменная, не имеющая присвоенного значения, обладает типом
>   undefined. Также возвращают undefined метод или инструкция, если
>   переменная, участвующая в вычислениях, не имеет присвоенного значения.
>   Функция возвращает undefined, если она не возвращает какого-либо
>   значения. [Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Динамическая типизация - зло в чистом виде.

Comment: @Khipster Это холивар :) У того и другого подхода есть свои плюсы и минусы и преимущества над другим подходом.. мне динамическая типизация приносит огромные проблемы, например когда в ранних версиях PHP не было нормальной типизации и люди писали модули без документации и тестов, когда ты хочешь что-то изменить, ты начинаешь валяться в конвульсиях, так как функция могла возвращать аж все существующие типы! С другой стороны такой подход учит тебя обязательно писать тесты и документацию, и показывает как правильно использовать инструмент.

Comment: А динамическая типизация на сервере - это зло в чистом виде х10.

Comment: @Khipster подозреваю, что вы (да и автор, возможно -- возможно, случайно) путаете слабую/строгую и динамическую/статическую. Ответ демонстрирует в первую очередь слабость типизации в JS и связанные с этим опасности.

Comment: @D-side да, соглашусь, спасибо, ошибочно привел проблемы приведения типов  в слабой типизации к динамической :)

Comment: забавно, но второй случай как-то странно рассмотрен :-) ну и что, что undefined - свойство глобального объекта? Почему же возвращается **строка** _undefined_? :)

Comment: @Grundy Упс, видимо задумался и забыл вставить это в ответ :) Ответ по преобразованию типа undefined в string можно найти по данной ссылке в официальном стандарте на русском: http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.8 или оригинал на англ: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8

Comment: @Firepro, так стоит добавить это в ответ, а не в комментарий :-)

Comment: @Grundy как написал комментарий, так сразу добавил в ответ же :)

Comment: @Firepro, настолько незаметно, что лучше словами написать